# SSH tunnel from webpage

Tags: web, ssh-tunnel

Is it possible to create a SSH tunnel by JavaScript from a webpage to access resources on a internal network? Do I need a jump box for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called
[Web-based SSH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web-based_SSH),
which requires a server-side component that does the actual work.
So in essence, JavaScript can only go via a server that does the SSH
part, while the client only transmits key-strokes to the server and
processes the terminal output returned by the server.

If you are looking for such software, the following Github projects might be
useful:

- [ssh2](https://github.com/mscdex/ssh2)
  (uses [node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/))
- [open-ssh-tunnel](https://github.com/parro-it/open-ssh-tunnel)

Comment: I want to create a tunnel from a website to a host behind the SSH server. RDS does something simular with RDweb.